# How to change the content of viewport property of meta tag in Plone 4.1?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

How can I change the content of viewport property of meta tag in Plone 4.1?

For example:

Plone defines:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.6666; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=0.6666"
```

But I need:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your are using a Theme based on plonetheme.sunburst.

Unfortunately your part ist hard coded directly in the [main_template.pt](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.sunburst/blob/1.1.6/plonetheme/sunburst/skins/sunburst_templates/main_template.pt#L48)
Which means the only way to change this, is to customise the main_template.pt.

You an either to this thru the ZMI...

> portal_skins -> sunburst_templates -> main_template.pt -> Click "Customize" button -> Change your line

... or using [z3c.jbot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot) to customise the template (you need your own policy, theme, or customisation package).

If you have your own package, you can also register a [new skins directory](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/templates_css/skin_layers.html) and put the customised main_template into it.

Answer (score 3):

If your're using a Diazo Theme, you could re-define the value via "replace" directive

> http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/advanced.html

Comment: This is in fact the easiest way, if you are using a diazo theme anyways.